# How to sort with multiple fields desc and asc for in spring data web?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-data

I have requirement to sort elements with multi fields asc and desc in spring data web without writing more code 
For example i want to sort cars by make desc and id asc

Currently i can do it ether asc or desc by both fields

http://ip:port/cars?sort=make,id,desc

Or

http://ip:port/cars?sort=make,id,asc

Is there anyway to sort by both fields by passing parameters like below

http://ip:port/cars?sort=make,id,desc,asc

and get data sorted by both fields first desc ,second asc  without write more code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query param should look like: http://ip:port/cars?sort=make,desc&sort=id,asc

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help